# Is there any software package for quantum chemistry that includes CAMB3LYP?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I want to do calculations on systems with photoinduced electron transfer, and I've read that the Coloumb Attenuating Method is a modification of the functionals that makes calculations including long-range electron transfer more accurate. Unfortunately I can't seem to find CAM in Gaussian. Is there some other software I should look at?

Comment: CAM-B3LYP is implemented in Gaussian. Please look again.

Comment: CAM-B3LYP is also implemented in [ORCA](http://orcaforum.cec.mpg.de) (free, but for non-commercial use only).

Comment: It seems I have an old version of the Gaussview program I use to generate my input files. I will just have to write the input file manually instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CAM-B3LYP is present in [Gaussian](http://gaussian.com/dft/), [Q-Chem](http://www.q-chem.com/qchem-website/manual/qchem44_manual/sect-DFT.html), [GAMESS](http://www.msg.ameslab.gov/gamess/GAMESS_Manual/input.pdf), [NWChem](http://www.nwchem-sw.org/index.php/Release66:Density_Functional_Theory_for_Molecules), [ORCA](https://orcaforum.cec.mpg.de/), [DALTON](http://daltonprogram.org/), [DIRAC](http://diracprogram.org/doc/release-12/tutorials/dft/cam.html), and perhaps other major software packages, either as `cam-b3lyp` or `camb3lyp`, however keywords are entered.

Notably it isn't available in TURBOMOLE as of version 7.1.

Comment: It should be noted, that no DFT calculation is good without calibration.

Comment: Of course. Additionally, there are better long-range-corrected functionals than CAM-B3LYP (at least in theory), but that's a topic for another thread.

Comment: ... and [Dalton](http://daltonprogram.org/) ([example](http://daltonprogram.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=68) for $1 ~\gamma$, $2 ~ \gamma$, and $3 ~ \gamma$ absorption) and [Dirac](http://www.diracprogram.org/doku.php) ([example](http://diracprogram.org/doc/release-12/tutorials/dft/cam.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Not all of QM program use adirect keyword of functional. Some of them you've to mix an ingredient of % functional, says in NWCHem. In that, you aint use keyword 'cam-b3lyp' directly, you need the combination of keywords like

> xc xcamb88 1.00 lyp 0.81 vwn_5 0.19 hfexch 1.00 
>   cam 0.33 cam_alpha 0.19 cam_beta 0.46